# IntelliSense not working VS2008 VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

I realize this question has been asked before, but I was not able to find anything that worked for me yet.

Things I have tried:

- Switched settings back to default (mulitple ways)
- Project Builds/Compiles fine
- Closed VS and restarted

The only thing I haven't been able to try is deleting the ".ncb" file, but that's only because I can't find it. In fact not a single one of all our projects have such a file!

So the first question is why can't I find this file in the solution's root directory? The only file I have there besides the .sln is the .suo.

Then if that doesn't work what other options do I have short of un-installing and re-installing?

As for how it happened this might help. While using VS2008 and VSS6.0 (yuck) I made a number of changes to a lot of files via Find&Replace that I didn't mean to(had Entire Solution selected instead of current document). To undo the changes I exited without saving, reopened the solution, then Undid checkout. After that I lost intellisense! I can't imaging how they're related but it might help.

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: What source language: C++, C#, ...?

Comment: Un-installing/Re-installing should be your very very last option. Before I got to that point my second last option of last resort would be to delete the solution file and recreate it.

Comment: Sorry it's VB and yes I'd hate to waste a whole day un/re-installing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

I figured out how to fix it. Apparently while I was undoing those changes I somehow excluded the file that I wasn't getting intellisense in from the project.

I just right-clicked on it and said "Include in Project" and viola! Intellisense worked again.

Sorry for the false alarm but I appreciate the effort.

Jeff

Answer (score 2):

Is this for C++ code? If it is, my suggestion is not to try fixing built-in IntelliSense at all, rather try some 3rd party replacement. My favourite is definitely [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/), which is lot more robust (it almost never stops working, and it is able to parse even very complicated templated and preprocessed stuff, which often makes IntelliSense "lost".

Visual Assist works with other languages including Visual Basic, however this is something I have no practical experience with. Still, there is a free trial - you may try it, I expect it will be superior to IntelliSense even for VB.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliSense usually stops working when it can't compile correctly.  Try a new simple project from scratch and see if it works, if it does you have your answer.